# Remove .html Before Redirecting in Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the rule below which works perfectly, however My oldsite urls have .html and me newsite doesn't. Is it possible to strip the .html before redirecting? e.g.

www.oldsite.com/mypage.html

gets redirected to

www.newsite.com/subdir/mypage/

e.g.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.co.uk/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.newsite.co.uk/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so `www.oldsite.com/mypage.html` will be redirected to `www.newsite.com/subdir/mypage`